# UISEGMENTEDCONTROL moves when a cell in segment 0 clicked and moved to segment 1

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have to create a segment with 3, segment 0 has a `uicollection` view when a cell inside the `uicollection` is clicked it should move to the second segment which is segment 1.. but I have kept one `UIVIEW` in storyboard which carries the `uicollection` view in segment 1. So I need to add one more `UIVIEW` in storyboard. Please help me. I will attach the storyboard for your reference.

[image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        

}
```

when I click the cell it should move to next segment which is segment 1. for that where I have to code either in `didselectmethod` or the action part in segmented control.

```
@IBAction func segmented_tapped_action(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is all about, but have you tried `self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex{

    case 0:
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategorySegmentCollectionViewCell {
            self.segmented_Control.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)
            segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
            collectionView.reloadData()
            print(cell)
        }
```

this will be the solution. Thanks for your support